# Using a macro to create new function LookUpConcat but it crashes

Tags: vba, excel

I need to join text from cells together into one cell.  I found this macro which was written sometime ago, which may be my problem, that creates a new function in excel called `LookUpConcat`.  The first time I copied it into my VBA and create the formula `=LookUpConcat($B$2,Usage!$AA$2:$AA$5000,$AG$2:$AG$5000," ")` it seemed to worked great.  Then it start crashing and giving me a `#NAME` error, so I started fresh. Now it says it has a compile error at each of the = signs in the beginning.  (String = " ", Boolean = True,....)

```
Function LookUpConcat(ByVal SearchString As String, SearchRange As Range, ReturnRange As Range, _
                       Delimiter As String = " " , MatchWhole As Boolean = True, _
                       UniqueOnly As Boolean = False,  MatchCase As Boolean = False)

  Dim X As Long, CellVal As String, ReturnVal As String, Result As String

  If (SearchRange.Rows.Count > 1 And SearchRange.Columns.Count > 1) Or _
     (ReturnRange.Rows.Count > 1 And ReturnRange.Columns.Count > 1) Then
    LookUpConcat = CVErr(xlErrRef)
  Else
    If Not MatchCase Then SearchString = UCase(SearchString)
    For X = 1 To SearchRange.Count
      If MatchCase Then
        CellVal = SearchRange(X).Value
      Else
        CellVal = UCase(SearchRange(X).Value)
      End If
      ReturnVal = ReturnRange(X).Value
      If MatchWhole And CellVal = SearchString Then
        If UniqueOnly And InStr(Result & Delimiter, Delimiter & ReturnVal & Delimiter) > 0 Then     GoTo Continue
        Result = Result & Delimiter & ReturnVal
      ElseIf Not MatchWhole And CellVal Like "*" & SearchString & "*" Then
        If UniqueOnly And InStr(Result & Delimiter, Delimiter & ReturnVal & Delimiter) > 0 Then     GoTo Continue
        Result = Result & Delimiter & ReturnVal
      End If
Continue:
    Next

    LookUpConcat = Mid(Result, Len(Delimiter) + 1)
```

Comment: If you provide default parameter values then I think you also need the `Optional` keyword

Comment: Whoa. Backup and explain clearly exactly what you are trying to do.  If all you want to do is concatenate a range, there are far simpler UDF's floating around.  If you need to do something more complex, EXPLAIN that by EDITING your post.  When you write *"I need to join text from cells together into one cell"*, that may not even require a UDF if it is only a few cells.  And if it is multiple cells in a contiguous range, something as simple as  **For each Cell in Range: Concat = Concat & Cell: Next Cell** will do the job.

Comment: On a sheet in the workbook I have the formula    =LookUpConcat(what to lookup,where to find lookup,return this item). The items it is returning can be none, one, or many. If many they are seperated by " ". The items are text.  The formula is pulled down the worksheet with the lookup item changing.  So knowing that would your suggestion work and make this macro run quicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those equals signs you reference are designating default values for those parameters in case you pass nothing to the function for that variable. **Excel doesn't want you to assign a default value without explicitly declaring those parameters as optional.** Change the following line:

```
Function LookUpConcat(ByVal SearchString As String, SearchRange As Range, ReturnRange As Range, _
                   Delimiter As String = " " , MatchWhole As Boolean = True, _
                   UniqueOnly As Boolean = False,  MatchCase As Boolean = False)
```

To:

```
Function LookUpConcat(ByVal SearchString As String, SearchRange As Range, ReturnRang As Range, _
                   Optional Delimiter As String = " ", Optional MatchWhole As Boolean = True, _
                   Optional UniqueOnly As Boolean = False, Optional MatchCase As Boolean = False)
```

Can I assume you have an `End If` followed by an `End Function` after this code?? After those changes, it compiles on my machine.

Comment: Thank you that worked and as soon as I see what Ron Rosenfeld is talking about I will mark this answered.  The End If and End Function did get placed in the wrong area too.  Corrected that.